# IOS Swift load (local)image with URL

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

Can we load images found locally on the device with SDWebimage using URL option? if yes then Im trying to use SDWebimage to display images, below is my code and i am unable to load image in the imageview. its still blank. kindly help me to understand what im doing wrong?

```
func addImage(sender: AnyObject){

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){

        picController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum;
        picController.allowsEditing = true
        self.presentViewController(picController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
    titleImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the UIImagePickerController delegate 
imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

will have the info as described in documentation-

> A dictionary containing the original image and the edited image, if an
>   image was picked; or a filesystem URL for the movie, if a movie was
>   picked. The dictionary also contains any relevant editing information.
>   The keys for this dictionary are listed in Editing Information Keys.

so if it is image that you are looking at, it will be right there in the dictionary itself.

You can get original image directly-

```
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]

if let image = image {
   //Set this image to your image view directly
   titleImageView.image = image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here  `info` as a `NSDictonary` and get that key is `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`

see this code :

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:NSDictionary!) {
    var tempImage:UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
    imagePreview.image  = tempImage

    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```